# How can I add bundle into react-native App

Tags: ios, react-native

I search some answers but did not find a special solution for adding with command for ios.

solution #1:

1. generate jsbundle with command `react-native bundle`
2. open project with Xcode and add files to...
3. update AppDelegate.m file to point to jsbundle
4. run command `xcodebuild -workspace` to build app
5. the app would be run on simulator without local server (react-native start)

for these steps, i would like to create a script to run without manual operation. especially for xcode add files, how can i add jsbundle / assets with command and build jsbundle into App?

Thanks

Comment: after generate jsbundle and how to add .jsbundle / assets into /ios folder with command line (don't ask me to open Xcode to add files... since i would like to run with command)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
npx react-native run-ios --configuration Release
```

Comment: i don't want to run 'react-native start' and would like to include .jsbundle file in application bundle.

Comment: If you take a look into generated ipa file you will see the jsbundle.